# Swift __NSCFConstantString * "NSInvalidArgumentException" Error

Tags: swift

I am unable to figure out what this error is coming from. I am also new to Swift and not very good with english. If anyone can help me it will be very appreciated.

Swift File from where the error is coming from

```
class ShopViewController : UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    var Name = "John Doe"
    var Address = "123 Main ST"
    var Quantity = "1"
    var BTCADDRE = "12"
    
    var purchaseAmount = Int(0)
    var Price = Int(15)
    
    var purchasePrice = Int(0)
    
    @IBAction func getName(sender: UITextField){
        Name = sender.text ?? "John Doe"
    }
    
    @IBAction func getAddr(sender: UITextField){
        Address = sender.text ?? "123 Main ST"
    }
    
    @IBAction func getQuan(sender: UITextField){
        Quantity = sender.text ?? "1"
    }
    
    @IBAction func getBTCA(sender: UITextField){
        BTCADDRE = sender.text ?? "12"
    }
    
    @IBAction func buy(sender: Any){
        purchaseAmount = Int(Quantity) ?? Int(0)
        purchasePrice = purchaseAmount * Price
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Complete Purchase?", message: "Complete Purchase for: " + String(purchasePrice), preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: nil ))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        
        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
    
    func confBuy() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Purchase Complete", message: "Purchase Complete", preferredStyle: .alert)
        //alert.addAction(UIAlertController(title: "OK", message: .cancel, preferredStyle: nil))
        
        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Update: It only happens with func getName(sender: UITextField)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had multiple actions connected to the getName TextField